# How to convert safetensors model to onnx model?

Tags: python, pytorch, onnx, huggingface, safe-tensors

I want to convert a `model.safetensors` to ONNX, unfortunately I haven't found enough information about the procedure. The documentation of `safetensors` package isn't enough and actually is not clear even how to get the original (pytorch in my case) model, since when I try something as

```
with st.safe_open(modelsafetensors, framework="pt") as mystf:
   ...
```

the `mystf` object has `get_tensor('sometensorname')` but it seems hasn't any `get_model()` method or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is what I found for the conversion of model:

[Convertor](https://github.com/xenova/transformers.js?tab=readme-ov-file#convert-your-models-to-onnx)

Download from repo `convert.py` and `requirements.txt` from [scripts](https://github.com/xenova/transformers.js/tree/main/scripts), put it to some folder.

1. Create a virtual environment by running `python -m venv .venv`
2. Activate it by running `source .venv/bin/activate`
3. Install requirements by `pip install -r requirements.txt`
4. Run a script for converting a model, in my case it was: `python convert.py --quantize --model_id BAAI/bge-small-en-v1.5`